# AWS Python Lambda Authentication for Google reCaptcha Enterprise Client Using Non-secret JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, federated-identity

Here is what I currently have:

- A gcp project with a Workload Provider Pool set up with my AWS account as the provider.
- A gcp Service Account with the necessary roles for my recaptcha assessment creation (`Workload Identity User` and `reCAPTCHA Enterprise Agent`).
- The SA has been granted permission for the Pool.
- I have a generated non-secret json config file for the SA impersonation from my AWS Lambda, which looks like this:

```json
{
    "type": "external_account",
    "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/<my_account_number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<my-pool-name>/providers/aws-provider",
    "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:aws:token-type:aws4_request",
    "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/<my-service-account-name>@<my-gcp-project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
    "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
    "credential_source": {
        "environment_id": "aws1",
        "region_url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone",
        "url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials",
        "regional_cred_verification_url": "https://sts.{region}.amazonaws.com?Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15"
    }
}
```

Now I want my AWS Lambda to use this so I can successfully do the following:

```py
client = recaptchaenterprise_v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient(credentials=???)
```

and do the calls I need for my recaptcha stuff.

How on earth do I do that? All online examples seem to use either the old secret key way or aren't using a lambda or aren't using the google python lib, etc...

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/docs/user-guide.rst#using-external-identities

Comment: @JohnHanley if you wanna convert that to an answer and just paste the relevant code for the AWS block I'd accept it. Worked for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: I would but I need to verify the code that I would write as an answer. Instead, can you post your solution so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnHanley for the [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/docs/user-guide.rst#using-external-identities) to the relevant documentation.

Here is how it is done:

```py
import json
from google.auth import aws
from google.cloud import recaptchaenterprise_v1
from google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise_v1 import Assessment

# The JSON in the question in string form loaded from the AWS Lambda's env variables.
service_account_json_info = "{ ... }" 

service_account_json_info_dict = json.loads(service_account_json_info)
credentials = aws.Credentials.from_info(service_account_json_info_dict)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

# This then works and can make the calls it's authorized to do according to the GCP config.
client = recaptchaenterprise_v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient(credentials=scoped_credentials)
```